# owl-carousel scrolls all divs together

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

Please see the attached snippet...

owl-carousel even in this minimal setup, scrolls all divs inside it, as if it was one div!

Each element should be able to scroll indipendently, as in this demo

http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/one.html

I am going bananas here...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#home-carousel").owlCarousel({
      autoPlay: 3000,
      singleItem:true
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>

<div id="above-the-fold-remaining" style="height:150px">
 <div id="home-carousel" class="owl-carousel">
  <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x150.jpg" alt="demo 1" /></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x150.jpg" alt="demo 2" /></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x150.jpg" alt="demo 3" /></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

OK!

I forgot to include the css file

everything works now